# Dynamic AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to dynamically insert a `ng-options` directive inside `<select>` elements across my application, which all have their own class names and other directives (like `ng-if` and so).

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="model" class="myClass" ng-if="condition || true" my-directive>
  </select>
  <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

---

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {
      $scope.items = [{ label: "foo", value: "foofoo"},
                      { label: "bar", value: "barbar"}];
      $elem.removeAttr('my-directive'); // Prevents infinite loop
      $elem.attr('ng-options', 'item as item.label for item in items');
      $compile($elem)($scope);
    }
  }
})
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = null;
  $scope.$watch('model', function(val) { console.log('•', val) });
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/raphaelyancey/pen/OMPzZV?editors=101)

The idea is that `my-directive` should be replaced by `ng-options` and the element should still behave like normal with all the other directives that are applied to it.

I don't understand why `ng-model` doesn't get updated, as the directive's scope is the parent scope (`scope: false`). I tried to make the DOM modifications in the `compile` step of the directive, but `$scope.items` gets unknown and the dropdown isn't even populated.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you need to set really high priority of your directive to make its compile function execute before ngModel's one (and ngIf's too). For this, don't compile manually but implement compile function of the directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      priority: 10000,
      terminal: true,
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.attr('ng-options', 'item as item.label for item in items').removeAttr('my-directive');
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }
  })
```

You also need to remember, that if you use directives that create new scopes (like ngIf, ngInclude, etc.) you might get unexpected behaviours when the model won't update because Angular will write value into child's scope model. In your demo I used `$parent` to refer proper scope explicitly, but it's better to use controllerAs notation to eliminated such problems.

You also don't want to set items in directive link function, but I guess this is just for demo purposes, you should move it to controller.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVwQYr?editors=101

Comment: I was busy compiling an answer when you beat me to it. Just one question why do you need the `ng-if="condition || true"` directive to make it work? Please see first example where `ng-if="condition || true"` is present. Then on the second example the `ng-if="condition || true"` is not present and the `select` options are not populated. 1. https://jsfiddle.net/vg2wgamg/ 2. https://jsfiddle.net/2qzjkpqL/ I can always ask the question and let you answer it there?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt This is really tricky problem. I'm not clear myself what causes this behaviour, it is however has to do with additional nested scope created by ngIf. The solution I found is to add `terminal: true` instruction to prevent further compiling (?). I also found that it is necessary to manually compile element in link function. Check updated demo.

Comment: Okay. I tested and your previous example worked fine as it was in the compile function of the directive. I dont think you need to manually use the `$compile` service as you did in your updated code example